# Temporal adjective for "As old as time itself"?

Tags: single-word-requests, time

Is there a single-word adjective describing something that has lasted forever? I'd be quite surprised if there wasn't. I can't ponder anything at the moment.

I'd imagine it's use to be something along *"He bares the ancient prophecy".* However ancient does not seem like a long enough time period. ***Eternal*** gives the impression that it *will* last forever. Whereas I'm looking for something that could last for a finite amount of time, however, *has* lasted since the start of time.

Edit: As pointed out, *forever* is very broad. And indeed I'm looking for broad answers. However, to be 100% clear. I'm looking for a word describing something that has existed since the start of time / the universe / the big bang. Something that defines an existence much longer than earth, not to mention humanity. I.e. the longest possible timespan between the past and now.

Comment: "Eons" comes to mind. "Time immemorial" is two words. Not adjectives though...

Comment: @anongoodnurse Ahah, perhaps "eonic" would fit the bill.

Comment: Can you give us an example sentence showing how you want to use the word? That's technically required for single-word-requests, and will help us give you the nuance that you want. Off the top of my head I can think of ***antediluvian, eternal, timeless, immemorial***, etc. Doing some research digging of your own with a dictionary or thesaurus, and telling us what you've found and why that doesn't work, is also very helpful.

Comment: "*has lasted*" means so far, so apparently you are looking for something that will also last forever, as in *eternal*.

Comment: would [half as old as time](http://www.poetryatlas.com/poetry/poem/3771/petra.html) be old enough?

Comment: @1006a Yes, of course.

Comment: @ab2 Unfortunately no, that would imply there was a time period that has existed before the object in questions's existence.

Comment: @ab2 Ah, indeed.

Comment: 'Venerable' is in the same area.

Comment: Call me compulsive, but I have to repeat that the start of time (for our universe) was the Big Bang, approximately 13.8 billion years ago.  Protons formed about one microsecond after the Big Bang, hydrogen atoms much, much later.  Our sun isn't even a first generation star.  The entire history and prehistory of the genus homo is only about 2 million years. Spoken language is maybe 50,000 years old, but we know nothing of language earlier than roughly 5,000 years ago.  Please make it clearer what you want.

Comment: Technically (whatever that means) eternal does mean that it *has* lasted forever; sempiternal means that it might not have always been but it always will be. That said, you are looking for something which can end, but has no start. I like *without-start*, as opposed to *without-end*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Adjective: **primeval**  prI'mee-vul
>
> Having existed from the beginning; in an earliest or original stage or state
>
> "the forest primeval";
>
> - aboriginal, primal, primaeval, primordial
>
> See also: early
>
> Encyclopedia: Primeval

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=primeval)

Comment: I'm not sure that _primeval_ and _prophecy_ collocate too well.